# How do I check Mysql row for text?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to check if a row in my table contains a specific string.
If it does, I want to get the user who has the specific string.
My table looks like this:
[The picture](http://prntscr.com/df5urs)

I want to check the String "Peter", in the Address column/row.
How do I scan through it, and find it?
Then after doing that, how would I check for the ID of the user who owns the String?
I appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: Please read first about how to ask questions here. Note that you are expected to be able to use the tools you refer to, that you are expected to know the basics of programming, that you post your own code you are working with and are able to point out the issues and what specific details you need help with. Your current question is far to broad to be answered here. It basically asks: "tell me everything about programming and databases". That is a question that cannot be answered in the Q&A format used on this page.

Answer (score 2):

Basics od mysql. Wildcard `%` tells db engine that we expect some characters before and after 'Peter' string.

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE Address LIKE '%Peter%'
```

Matches:

```
"Peter's address"
"It is Peter's address"
"Address of Peter"
```

Answer (score 0):

Write the SQL command to scan the data.Command for your problem looks like ::

```
select * from Mytable where address="peter";
```

Answer (score 0):

Some alternatives to LIKE
given

```
MariaDB [BANK]> select * from customer;
+------+---------+-------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------------+------+--------------+-------+
| id   | version | title | FirstName | Middlenames | LastName | Gender | Dob        | Dod  | Warning_flag | Worth |
+------+---------+-------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------------+------+--------------+-------+
|    1 |    1.00 | Mr    | fname1    | NULL        | lname1   | m      | 1990-01-01 | NULL | NULL         | NULL  |
|    2 |    1.00 | Mrs   | fname1    | NULL        | lname1   | f      | 1990-01-01 | NULL | NULL         | NULL  |
|    3 |    1.00 | Mrs   | fname1    | NULL        | lname1   | f      | 1990-01-01 | NULL | NULL         | NULL  |
+------+---------+-------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------------+------+--------------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [BANK]> SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER
    -> WHERE INSTR(LASTNAME,'a') > 0;
+------+---------+-------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------------+------+--------------+-------+
| id   | version | title | FirstName | Middlenames | LastName | Gender | Dob        | Dod  | Warning_flag | Worth |
+------+---------+-------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------------+------+--------------+-------+
|    1 |    1.00 | Mr    | fname1    | NULL        | lname1   | m      | 1990-01-01 | NULL | NULL         | NULL  |
|    2 |    1.00 | Mrs   | fname1    | NULL        | lname1   | f      | 1990-01-01 | NULL | NULL         | NULL  |
|    3 |    1.00 | Mrs   | fname1    | NULL        | lname1   | f      | 1990-01-01 | NULL | NULL         | NULL  |
+------+---------+-------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------------+------+--------------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [BANK]>
MariaDB [BANK]> SELECT *
    -> from customer
    -> WHERE position('a' in lastname) > 0;
+------+---------+-------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------------+------+--------------+-------+
| id   | version | title | FirstName | Middlenames | LastName | Gender | Dob        | Dod  | Warning_flag | Worth |
+------+---------+-------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------------+------+--------------+-------+
|    1 |    1.00 | Mr    | fname1    | NULL        | lname1   | m      | 1990-01-01 | NULL | NULL         | NULL  |
|    2 |    1.00 | Mrs   | fname1    | NULL        | lname1   | f      | 1990-01-01 | NULL | NULL         | NULL  |
|    3 |    1.00 | Mrs   | fname1    | NULL        | lname1   | f      | 1990-01-01 | NULL | NULL         | NULL  |
+------+---------+-------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------------+------+--------------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [BANK]>
MariaDB [BANK]> SELECT *
    -> from customer
    -> WHERE locate('a',lastname)  > 0;
+------+---------+-------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------------+------+--------------+-------+
| id   | version | title | FirstName | Middlenames | LastName | Gender | Dob        | Dod  | Warning_flag | Worth |
+------+---------+-------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------------+------+--------------+-------+
|    1 |    1.00 | Mr    | fname1    | NULL        | lname1   | m      | 1990-01-01 | NULL | NULL         | NULL  |
|    2 |    1.00 | Mrs   | fname1    | NULL        | lname1   | f      | 1990-01-01 | NULL | NULL         | NULL  |
|    3 |    1.00 | Mrs   | fname1    | NULL        | lname1   | f      | 1990-01-01 | NULL | NULL         | NULL  |
+------+---------+-------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------------+------+--------------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```